# Powershell automated testing code freezes when pop up window appears in GUI.

Tags: powershell, jenkins, automation, automated-tests

I'm using Jenkins to perform some automated web testing on a web application.

I'm using powershell to automatically fill out forms, return values, etc. But sometimes a popup window will appear mid test. Weather its an error message or a sub form that needs to be filled out.

When this happens though, my code freezes indefinitely and I need to either exit out of the build or manually close the pop up window myself (defeating the purpose of automated testing).

Ideally I would like to be able to select the open pop up window as an object and fill out forms/ click buttons on it, but my code just freezes and doesn't give me chance.

Would anyone have any advice on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Jenkins but here is a PowerShell function that shows a Messagebox that will disapear after a timeout interval specified in milli seconds. To this popup won't be blocking.

```
function Show-Messagebox
{
    param([String]$Title, [String]$Message, [Int]$TimeOut=2000)

    $TypeDef = @'

    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Win32API
    {
        private const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
        private static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        public static void ShowMessageBox(string Message, string Caption, int TimeOut = 2000)
        {
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeOut) { AutoReset = false };
            timer.Elapsed += delegate
            {
               IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, Caption);
               if (hWnd.ToInt32() != 0) PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
           };

           timer.Enabled = true;
           MessageBox.Show(Message, Caption);
       }

   }
'@

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeDef -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms

    [Win32API]::ShowMessageBox($Message, $Title, $TimeOut)
}
```

The function can be called like so:

```
Show-Messagebox -Title "The Title" -Message "The complete message"
```

It's a little clumsy having to put the whole type definition of a class in C# code as a here string into the function (there a no white spaces allowed before the end mark '@ of the here string) but it's still a simple copy&paste solution.

If you replace the [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show()-calls in a PoweShell script with this function there should be no blocking Messageboxes any more.